# Onclick method not found in parent or ancestor context

Tags: java, android, buttonclick, android-appcompat

I get an error for a very simple thing. I have created a test button and an onClick method to just change the layout. I did it in a simple way so you could understand my problem better.

This is my button method:

```
 public void accountButton (View v){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
}
```

And this is the xml file of my button:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeTxt"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
    android:onClick="accountButton"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />
```

I get the following error when i click the button:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   accountButton(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

Comment: Post your activity code too.

Answer (score 2):

You may be calling your `setContentView` method from another activity. This method inflates the layout.

If it's called outside the activity the layout belongs to, the button won't be found. The most common way to initilize an activity from another is by intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then, inside your activity you call `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout)` to inflate the layout. If you do this, you can call the `onClick(View view)` referred in the xml file from inside your activity normally.

Comment: first sentence of this is all I needed. Should be available on other versions of similar question

Answer (score 1):

For those that still have issues, in Android Studio or Intellij IDE, this is likely to a cached version of the class you are using (or its predecessors), that is not being recompiled.

Do an "Invalidate Cache/restart" and your problems are likely to go away.

When I had this issue occur repeatedly, I noticed that it was due to a "File Lock", triggered by Google Drive, that was making a copy of my File(s). Temporary disabling that solved all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

you should not call  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);` inside `onClick()` mentod of **button**.you have to call setContentView(R.layout.activity_start); inside `oncreate()` method.

follow the steps to achieve it.

1. implement `OnClickListener` in your class
2. initialize the button in `onCreate()`

   ```
   Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   ```
3. set the `setOnClickListener()` method for **button**

   ```
   btn.setOnClickListener()
   ```
4. then call the method outside of `oncreate()`

   ```
    public void accountButton (View v){  //do some thing which you want }
   ```